# Optimization of function which activates container depending of scrollTop

Tags: jquery, optimization, scrolltop

I am creating a website in which there is many containers who are activated when person are scrolling down and later on if person scrolls further would be deactivated. I am worried that scrolling will become very jagged this way. Maybe you know how could I improve it ?

```
$(window).scrollEnd(function(){ 
if( 200 < $(this).scrollTop() ) {
        if (1500 > $(this).scrollTop()) { 
                  if(fired == 0){
                    $("#loader_small").css("display", "block");
                    $('.section_two_video').load('test.html');
                    fired = 1;
                  }
            $(".section_two_video").stop().fadeIn("slow");
        }else {
            $(".section_two_video").stop().fadeOut("slow");
        }   
    } 
    else {
        $(".section_two_video").stop().fadeOut("slow");
    };
}, 300)

$.fn.scrollEnd = function(callback, timeout) {          
  $(this).scroll(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
      clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    }
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,timeout));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could underscore's debounce function:

```
function _debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;

    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

From the docs:

> Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
>   be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
>   N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
>   leading edge, instead of the trailing.

Use:

```
var func = _.debounce(function(e) {    
    // do work
}, 500); // once per 500ms

// Add the event listener
$(window).scrollEnd(func);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!